# Is my proposed method of modifying an Android asset-pack zip file to include new icons appropriate and functional?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-asset-delivery, android-assetpacks

I am currently engaged in the process of integrating asset_pack delivery within an Android application. To accomplish this, I am following the guidelines provided in the official Android documentation, accessible through the following link: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java.

At present, the integration is functioning properly. However, there is a requirement for a zip file containing assets located in the asset-pack-name/src/main/assets/your-asset-directories directory, as this file is subsequently downloaded onto the user's device.

As a developer, when I need to include any additional icons within this zip file, it becomes necessary to first extract its contents, make the desired modifications, and then repackage the assets into a new zip file.

To address this issue, I have devised a solution that involves the following steps:

1. Creating a separate folder within the asset_pack/src directory, specifically for storing the unzipped icons.
2. Implementing a Gradle task responsible for generating a new zip file containing the above mentioned folder, which is then placed within the asset_pack/src/main/assets directory.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights regarding whether this solution is deemed appropriate or if it may potentially introduce complications into the application's functionality.